# To pull off wearing something

Tags: word-in-context

I found the text below in a comedy series episode:

*No matters how big you are, in Cleveland everybody
seems to think they can pull off wearing shorts.*

What's the meaning of **pull off** in this context?

Comment: Did they definitely say "No matters"?  The standard expression is "No matter".

Comment: I just checked it and you're right., it's "no matter". Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Pull off" in American English (at least), is an idiom which means, generally, "to achieve or accomplish something, especially if it is difficult or unexpected".

In the context of wearing clothing or other "fashion", it means to "look good, acceptable in a given outfit".

In the comedy series, the implication is that shorts (lower body garment much like pants, but that typically end before the knees) are not fashionable on many people, especially larger/more obese people, due to the amount of the body that they expose; In Cleveland (a large city in Ohio), the comic insinuates/complains that regardless of body-type/size, people have a tendency to wear shorts (or at least think they look good in shorts), with the implication that they do not.

Answer (score 1):

I hate citing Urban Dictionary because so much of it is obscene, but they’re the only source I found that has the (relatively recent) idiom “pull off”:

> Pull off
>
> Someone that looks good when they wear or have a certain style.
>
> *Wow , he can pull off that hair style*

In your example, I think the speaker is saying that wearing shorts is generally accepted as not a good look for big (probably meaning fat) people, but the ones in Cleveland seem to think they can pull off that look.

Comment: There is an element of 'avoid looking stupid or ridiculous' in 'pull off'.

Comment: One pulls off a trick or feat of skill.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Wearing shorts is not a trick or feat of skill. This is a distinct usage that refers to style.

Comment: Wearing shorts and looking passable or good in them is an endeavour in which one might fail.